# @Html.ListBoxFor does not select initially selected elements

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, html-select, html-helper

I have this code in an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC view:

```
<div class="mb-3 position-relative">
    @{
        var listaAreas = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (Model.Areas != null && Model.Areas.Any())
        {
            var areasActuales = Model.Areas.Select(r => new SelectListItem() { Text = r.Area?.AreaNombre ?? string.Empty, Value = (r.Area?.AreaId ?? 0).ToString(), Selected = r.Selected });
            listaAreas.AddRange(areasActuales);
        }
    }
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Areas)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Areas, listaAreas, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100%", multiple = "multiple" })
</div>
```

This is `listaAreas` array when `ListBoxFor`is called:

[image]

Even when the only option has `Selected = true`, HTML SELECT tag appears no selected.

[image]

What is it going on here?

EDIT:

My last attempt, but no avail:

```
<div class="mb-3 position-relative">
    @{
        MultiSelectList? listaAreas = null;
        if (Model.Areas != null && Model.Areas.Any())
        {
            listaAreas = new MultiSelectList(Model.Areas.Where(a => a.Area != null).Select(a => a.Area), "AreaId", "AreaNombre", Model.Areas.Where(a => a.Selected).Select(a => a.Area?.AreaId).ToArray());
        }
    }
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Areas)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Areas, listaAreas, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100%", multiple = "multiple" })
</div>
```

Comment: Based on my testing I noticed that because of `multiple="multiple"` attribute causing the issue. Could you please let me know what is the expected result here you are looking for?

Comment: I have removed that attribute but the same happen.

Comment: Yeah I know, but what you are expecting here? the dropdown with one selected value? Or a dropdown with one selected value along with option for selecting many as well?

Answer (score 0):

> Even when the only option has Selected = true, HTML SELECT tag appears
> no selected. I have removed that attribute but the same happen

Based on your shared code snippet and description I have tried to investigate your issue. However, in asp.net core there's no pre-defined tag helper in order to display multi select dropdown. You ought to use javaScript based plugins if you want to implement either dropdown with checkbox or onclick keep the item selected within the dropdown box.

I have tried to use `bootstrap-multiselect.js` in order to demonstrate multi select dropdown with checkbox.

Let's have a look in practice, how we could implement that.

Controller:

```
public IActionResult MultiSelectCheckboxDropdown()
{
    var multiSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "C#" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "JavaScript" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Python" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Java" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "C++" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "6", Text = "Swift" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "7", Text = "Go" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "8", Text = "Ruby" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "9", Text = "TypeScript" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "10", Text = "PHP" }
        };

    ViewBag.multiSelectList = multiSelectList;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<h3>Multi select</h3>
@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.multiSelectList, null, new { @class = "selectpicker", multiple = "multiple", id = "Subjects_dropdown" })




<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
@section scripts {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/1.1.2/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/1.1.2/css/bootstrap-multiselect.min.css"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myMultiSelect').select2();
            $('#Subjects_dropdown').multiselect();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please modify the script and html according to your needs. As there's no built-in tag helper for multi select dropdown, so I tried to share with you this. You could have a look at [this document](https://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/gx93rwnk/) if you want to [check few more sample](https://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/gx93rwnk/).

Comment: Hello.... you are considering a dropdown list capable of multiselection. I just need to select default elements in a ListBox. When programming in MVC 5.0 (.NET Framework) I remember I used ListBoxFor helper (instead of DropDownListFor). That way, default selected elements were shown at page load. That is not happening here in .NET Core.